# How to proof that exists a sequence of real positive numbers for a sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, random-variables, real-numbers

Proof that for every sequence, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, of random variables, exists a sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of real positive numbers that $$\frac{(x_n)}{(b_n)} \rightarrow 0\qquad\text{ a.s.}$$

(that is a quocient of sequences)

$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in any probability space.

Comment: if $x_n<n$ take $b_n=n^2$ else take $b_n=(x_n)^2$.

Comment: This does not work: take $x_n$ to be the random variable that takes the value $\frac{1}{2}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and the value $n$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x_n$, you can pick a number $b_n$ such that
$P(x_n>\frac{1}{n}b_n)<1/n$.

Now, $\{\frac{x_n}{b_n}\nrightarrow 0\}$ must be contained in the intersection of infinitely many of the sets above (exercise: just write it down), so $P(\{\frac{x_n}{b_n}\nrightarrow 0\})=0$.

Comment: How to do proof that $P(x_n > \frac{1}{n}b_n)< 1/n$ ?